# Unix Epoch to date with sed

Tags: bash, date, sed, unix-timestamp

I wanna change unix epoch to normal date

i'm trying:

```
sed < file.json -e 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/`date -r \1`/g'
```

any hint?

Comment: Make sure to include any other as well as errors you're getting.

Comment: i just got on output:
date -r 15173526

Comment: Always including the output and any errors is part of asking for help on code, not just on stack overflow but anywhere.  Sure, we know what the problem is, but I believe it's worth taking time to improve the quality of questions when possible.

Answer (score 1):

With the lack of information from your post, I can not give you a better answer than this but it is possible to execute commands using `sed`!

You have different ways to do it you can use

1. directly `sed` `e` instruction followed by the command to be
   executed, **if you do not pass a command to `e` then it will treat the content of the pattern buffer as external command.**
2. use a simple substitute command with `sed` and pipe the output to `sh`

**Example 1:**

```
echo 12687278 | sed "s/\([0-9]\{8,\}\)/date -d @\1/;e"
```

**Example 2:**

```
echo 12687278 | sed "s/\([0-9]\{8,\}\)/date -d @\1/" |sh
```

**Test 1** (with Japanese locale `LC_TIME=ja_JP.UTF-8`):

[image]

**Test 2** (with Japanese locale `LC_TIME=ja_JP.UTF-8`):

[image]

**Remarks:**

1. I will let you adapt the date command accordingly to your system specifications
2. Since modern dates are longer than 8 characters, the `sed` command uses an
   open ended length specifier of at least 8, rather than exactly 8.

Comment: To add some color to this, the `date` invocation in this answer is for GNU `date`.  The OP asks with `date -r`, the equivalent for BSD date ( also on osx).

Comment: @DanFarrell: thank you a lot, indeed this field will keep on growing as time passes by

Answer (score 1):

Allan has a nice way to tackle dynamic arguments: write a script dynamically and pipe it to a shell!  It works.  It tends to be a bit more insecure because you could potentially pipe unintentional shell components to `sh` - for example if `rm -f some-important-file` was in the file along with the numbers , the `sed` pipeline wouldn't change that line, and it would also be passed to `sh` along with the date commands.  Obviously, this is only a concern if you don't control the input.  But mistakes can happen.

A similar method I much prefer is with `xargs`.  It's a bit of a head trip for new users, but very powerful.  The idea behind `xargs` is that it takes its input from its standard in, then adds it to the command comprised of its own non-option arguments and runs the command(s).  For instance,

```
$ echo -e "/tmp\n/usr/lib" | xargs ls -d
/tmp  /usr/lib
```

Its a trivial example of course, but you can see more exactly how this works by adding an `echo`:

```
echo -e "/tmp\n/usr/lib" | xargs echo ls -d
ls -d /tmp /usr/lib
```

The *input* to `xargs` becomes the additional *arguments* to the command specified in `xargs`'s own arguments.  Read that twice if necessary, or better yet, fiddle with this powerful tool, and the light bulb should come on.

Here's how I would approach what you're doing.  Of course I'm not sure if this is actually a logical thing  to do in your case, but given the detail you went into in your question, it's the best I can do.

```
$ cat dates.txt
Dates:
1517363346
```

I can run a command like this:

```
$ sed -ne '/^[0-9]\{8,\}$/ p' < dates.txt | xargs -I % -n 1  date -d @%
Tue Jan 30 19:49:06 CST 2018
```

Makes sense, because I used the commnad `echo -e "Dates:\n`date +%s`" > dates.txt` to make the file a few minutes before I wrote this post!  Let's go through it together and I'll break down what I'm doing here.

For one thing, I'm running sed with `-n`.  This tells it not to print the lines by default.  That makes this script work if not every line has an 8+ digit "date" in it.  I also added anchors to the start (`^`) and end (`$`) of the regex so the line had *only* the approprate digits ( I realize this may not be perfect for you, but without understanding your its input, I can't do better ).  These are important changes if your file is not entirely comprised of date strings.  Additionally, I am matching *at least* 8 characters, as modern date strings are going to be more like 10 characters long.  Finally, I added a command `p` to sed.  This tells it to print the matching lines, which is necessary because I specifically said *not* to print the nonmatching lines.

The next bit is the `xargs` iteslf.  The sed will write a date string out to xargs's standard input.  I set only a few settings for xargs. By default it will add the standard input to the end of the command, separated by a space.  I didn't want a space, so I used `-I` to specify a replacement string.  `%` doesn't have a special meaning; its just a placeholder that gets replaced with the input.  I used % because its not a special character but rarely is used in commands.  Finally, I added `-n 1` to make sure only 1 input was used per execution of `date`.  ( xargs can also add many inputs together, as in my `ls` example above).

The end result?  Sed matches lines that consist, exclusively, of 8 or more numeric values, outputting the matching lines.  The pipe then sends this output to `xargs`, which takes each line separately (`-n 1`) and, replacing the placeholder (`-I %`) with each match, then executes the date command.

This is a shell pattern I really like, and use every day, and with some clever tweaks, can be very powerful.  I encourage anyone who uses linux shell to get to know `xargs` right away.

There is another option for GNU sed users.  While the BSD land folks were pretty true to their old BSD unix roots, the GNU folks, who wrote their userspace from scratch, added many wonderful enhancements to the standards.  GNU Sed can apparently run a subshell command for you and then do the replacement for you, which would be dramatically easier.  Since you are using the bsd style date invocation, I'm going to assume you don't have gnu sed at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

### Using sed: tested with macOs only

There is a slight difference with the command `date` that should use the flag (-r) instead of (-d) exclusive to `macOS`

```sh
echo 12687278 | sed "s/\([0-9]\{8,\}\)/$(date -r \1)/g"
```

Results:

`Thu Jan  1 09:00:01 JST 1970`